# Push on the gas Vs Step on it

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I would appreciate it someone could let me know which one of the following choices would work properly in the self-made sentence below:

> - Put your foot on the clutch and ......................... and slowly release the clutch and put the car in the first gear.
>
> a) push on the gas
>
> b) step on it

For me, they both work properly and the only difference is that the choice "b" is a slang and the first one is not, but I'm not sure if they both sound natural to natives.

Comment: I'd say **press (on) the gas pedal**

Comment: Anyway it's better to rephrase it to: *"Push the clutch all the way down and select 1st gear. Afterwards, start gently pressing down the gas pedal while slowly releasing the clutch."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: All of the below is based on American English*

> step on it

"**Step on it**" is almost exclusively used when asking someone to speed up very quickly. For example, "Step on it! We're in a hurry!" This is because if you step (literally) on a gas petal, it will go all the way down, meaning you will accelerate as fast as possible.

> push on the gas

Generally we say "**press the gas**", "**press the gas pedal**", "**press ADJ on the gas pedal**".

In conclusion, I think you best option would be:

> Put your foot on the clutch, press gently on the gas pedal, and then slowly release the clutch while putting the car in the first gear.

Comment: You know that you can't do that in a real car?